# Login and Signin to Amazon Web Service Cognito error messages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm doing my app users management with the Cognito AmazonWebService and on AngularJS.

I can not figure out how to solve this problem :

After registering, users are receiving an email with a code to confirm it. When I try to enter and validate the code I have a pop-up message saying "`Error: the user is not authenticated`".

But if is I swap the steps I can not authenticated myself because I've this error: `"Your account must be confirmed"`.

EDIT: That's how I'm confirming the registration :

```
var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(_poolData);
    var userData = {
     Username : username,
     Pool : userPool
        };
            var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);
            cognitoUser.getAttributeVerificationCode('email', {
    onSuccess: function (result) {
        console.log('call result: ' + result);
    },
    onFailure: function(err) {
                    console.log("error");
        alert(err);
    },
    inputVerificationCode: function(code) {
                var verificationCode = prompt('Check you email for a verification code and enter it here: ' ,'');
            cognitoUser.verifyAttribute('email', verificationCode, this);
             }
        });
```

I have also try this code below :

```
var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);
cognitoUser.confirmRegistration('123456', true, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        alert(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('call result: ' + result);
});
```

But everytime I'm using the code you gave me to confirm an user I have this error message : `"ExpiredCodeException: Invalid code provided, please request a code again."` while user is well confirmed in my user pool...

How could I solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second code is the right one to be called. How long are you waiting to call?